# Hide/SHow if selected checkbox is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I am writing one application where a div is having Date, Start Time, End Time and location. And i have two check boxes:

1. Add Additional(checkbox) - if checked then one more set of div containing the same (date,time,location) will add.
2. Time/Place will be the same(checkbox)- If i check this check box and then check the first one then only date will be added to new div. All Start time, E Time and location will be hidden.

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" 
          ng-click="addMore(keyAdd)" 
          ng-model = "keyAdd" 
          ng-disabled="keyCount>2"> 
   <label for="keyAdd">Add Additional</label>
   &nbsp;
   &nbsp;
   <input type="checkbox"  
          ng-model = "keyOnlyDate" > 
   <label for="configDate">Time/Place will be the same</label>
   ```

**My controller**

In controller on-click even I am calling `addMore` function. As per current implementation it is hiding the time/Location of current row.
How to hide the next one.

```
  $scope.addMore = function(Attr){
     if (Attr && $scope.keyCount <= 2 && $scope.keyOnlyDate == false) {

        // $scope.selects.push({'datePicker':'','timePiker':''});
         $scope.selects.push({commDate : null,commEtime: null,commStime: null,configLoc:''});
                $(".dateContainer div.timePiker:last").show();
                $(".dateContainer label.configLocation:last").show();
                $(".dateContainer input.form-control:last").show();

         $scope.keyCount++;
         $scope.keyAdd = false;
         $scope.keyOnlyDate = false;
     }
     else if(Attr && $scope.keyCount <= 2 && $scope.keyOnlyDate == true){

         $scope.selects.push({commDate : null});

            $(".dateContainer div.timePiker:last").hide();
            $(".dateContainer label.configLocation:last").hide();
            $(".dateContainer input.form-control:last").hide();
        // $(".timePiker").hide();
         $scope.keyCount++;
         $scope.keyAdd = false;
         $scope.keyOnlyDate = false; 
     }
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example of what you trying to do for instance [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b1mh33Lc/).

Comment: Just one suggestion, try to use jqLite rather than jQuery as its not a good practice in angular

Comment: it seems like something you can replace with ng-change and ng-if.